# Fields depending on Lead status

Tags: lightning, leads

In Leads, I need to show/hide some fields depending on Lead status. Is there any way to do that without creation of a Lightning app or visualforce page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you're using a Lightning Record Page with a Path component.

You can add the fields that are relevant to each Lead Status to the Key Fields section of the Path configured for that field.

[image]

They'll display in a special section underneath the Path component.

[image]
You can then remove the fields from the Page Layout body, and they'll only be shown through the facility of the Path based on the current status of the Lead.